# Sort NSMutableArray using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I'm building an iOS app. I need to sort an NSMutableArray, so I used NSSortDescriptor. However, when I run my app, I unfortunately get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSTaggedPointerString 0xa000000343730314> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ID.'`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
customerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[rootDict allKeys]];
NSSortDescriptor *numberSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ID" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

[customerArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[numberSorter]];
```

Before, when I was just using `customerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[rootDict allKeys]];`, I had no issues. Once I added the other two lines, I started having problems. I checked where it crashes using breakpoints, and found that it crashes after trying to run the last line (`[customerArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[numberSorter]];`).

Any help would be appreciated, and I will gladly add more code if needed.

Comment: Are the elements in `customerArray` strings? If so, than you get the error because you're comparing the `ID` property of these elements, which doesn't exist. Remove the descriptor and use `[customerArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]` to compare the elements directly

Comment: @Doc You're right, they were strings, but I totally forgot, thinking it was the original array of dictionaries that I created earlier. Thank you, that worked. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As your error states `valueForUndefinedKey` which means that the objects inside the `NSMutableArray` i.e. customerArray in your case does not have a key with name ID (Undefined Key).

You need to check the objects inside your NSMutableArray.

Hope this solves your problem.